# iOS Splash screen appears when application is reloaded from background

Tags: ios, splash-screen

The splash screen of my app is showing when I reload the app after clicking the home button. It doesn't happen every time. It only happens when I press the home button while the app is creating a movie with AVFoundation and the reload the app.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening and how can I tackle the problem?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: app shows the splash screen only when it starts. And not when it resumes working from Background.

Comment: I have the same problem, doesn't happen on every run and doesn't trigger didFinishLaunchingWithOptions again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your app is actually being shut down, not just put in the background. It may be doing too much processing after being sent to the background so that the OS kills the app.

Comment: But when the app is reloaded it returns to the point where it was before put in the background (creating the video). If it is actually being shut down it would restart the app from the beginning no? The problem is just the splash screen appearing at that stage.

Comment: That depends... apps are supposed to save and restore their state across runs, so that the app appears to always be available. But if you haven't written your app that way then you're right, it must not be quitting. It may be that iOS displays the launch image when the app's state has been saved in secondary storage, or something along those lines. The intent of the launch image is to display your app's UI in a default state while the actual app is being loaded; using it instead as splash screen creates just the kind of problem you're seeing.